# Finding the rank

Tags: matrix-rank

Let A be a $3\times4$ matrix of rank $2$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b$. What is the value of $b$?

where,
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
        a & b & b & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

How to approach this?

I tried finding the row reduced echelon form. But I could not proceed further, any hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Row 1 and Row 2 are already linearly independent, so Row 3 should be a linear combination of Row 1 and Row 2. However, this community shouldn't be used for homework type questions.

Comment: What is your finding about the reduced echelon form?

Comment: I have got my answer .thanks